# Should I avoid giving a bounty to a new user?

Tags: discussion, support, bounties, new-users, privileges

At the beginning, learning the ropes of the system as you earn rep is very important.

Because of that, is it a bad idea to give a bounty to a very new user? They would get a number of privileges very soon, and I wonder if they wouldn't learn how to use them correctly.

Comment: IMHO, this would rather raise the question if (some) privileges should depend on reputation. The award of a bounty should not depend on anything else than the answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If they deserve the bounty you should award it to them. If the answer was good they'd probably already have 50 points or more from the up-votes so adding a bounty probably won't give them any more privileges than they already have.

As with voting your focus should be on the post not the poster. I shouldn't matter whether they have 1 point, 100 points or 1,000,000 points.

Comment: Your advice is correct IMO about how a user should behave (post, not poster), but maybe SE shouldn't count rep earned from bounties towards the privileges?